# Is it possible in VS Code to have split terminals in the same editor tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code you can split the view of a file in group so you get side by side of the file in one tab.

Is there a way to do this for tab terminal?

I know you can do that if you open the terminal in a panel but not as a tab.

Comment: Do you mean to see the same content on both sides? or two different terminal windows?

Comment: two different terminals but only in one tab

Comment: do you mean for terminal _editors_? I.e. terminals moved into the editor area?

Comment: yes, two terminal editors but on the same tab. so when I switch to another tab, the split is gone. so it is only split for the terminal tab

Answer (score -1):

On the top right corner of the terminal tab, there is a "Split Terminal" button: [image]

Can also be done by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>

Comment: I am talking about terminal editor not panel

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, at the time of this writing, no. There's no way to get this. You can have multiple terminal editors and put them in separate editor groups to achieve a kind of similar effect, but you can't split multiple terminals inside a single editor tab.

If you want such a feature, you'd need to [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).